# Is there a Planck uncertainty?

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, physical-constants

There are theories which place lower limits on length, time and temperature.  Is there a corresponding one for the lower limit for uncertainty?  Is there a probability so small it cannot exist in this universe?  Can the potential position of a particle be so small it cannot happen?

For example, could there be a barrier so impermeable we can say the probability of quantum tunneling is zero?  Not close to zero, but actually zero.

Comment: *"There are lower limits for length, mass, time, charge and temperature"* [citation needed] Except for temperature, none of these is fundamentally limited in currently accepted theories, no matter what you keep hearing about Planck *anything*.

Comment: @ACuriousMind That's a new one on me. Got some reading to back that up, perhaps in answer form? (I see how I misinterpreted Planck mass and charge)

Comment: I'd rather reverse the burden of proof - as long as you don't show me anything that shows there are these limits, I don't see what I could do to show the contrary. Note that the Planck quantities *are* fundamental limits in some theories like loop quantum gravity, but that is not a tested theory. In string theory, for example, the Planck scales are rather the scales at which particles emerge from the strings, and *not* fundamental limits. I've never seen a good argument why they should be fundamental limits in GR/QM/QFT (which is the current state of our accepted theories).

Comment: @ACuriousMind Fortunately the question is not directly tied to any of that so we don't have to go down that road. Would it be better if I added the phrase "is there a theory where..." to the question?

Comment: I guess that the probability of an electron to be in the same state of another electron would be zero. I'm not sure if that would hold in QFT.